# Embed a list/datagrid inside an edit form

Tags: react-admin

I'm new to `react` and `react-admin` specifically.

I'm trying to embed a `Datagrid` inside of an `Edit` form.

The `Edit` form props (`record`) has a child array of objects so I don't need to load the related records from the API using `ReferenceManyField` or something similar.

But I can't seem to find how to reference an array of the record as a `ListProp` for the List

If anyone has any examples that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If you provide some pseudo code at least it would be useful to get an idea of what is your final goal.

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm trying to embed a **Datagrid** inside of an **Edit** form.*

There is a stark difference in how those two components:

1. In terms of [how the components were built](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/Tutorial.html#adding-creation-and-editing-capabilities):

   - **`<Datagrid>`**
     It is an *iterator* component: it receives an *array of ids*, and a *data store*, and is supposed to iterate over the ids to display each record.

     Another example of iterator component is `<SingleFieldList>`.
   - **`<Edit>`**
     The `Edit` displays a form initialized with a *record* fetched from the API. The `<Edit>` component actually delegates the actual rendering of the form to a form component - usually `<SimpleForm>` (so you can change the child component, actually).
2. In terms of [mapping API endpoints](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/3.5/Tutorial.html#mapping-api-endpoints-with-resources):

   - **`<Datagrid>`**
     It's often used for `Read` operations thus used at endpoints where you're fetching lists of data e.g. `/users` or `/books`. Understanding this point will help you understand why (or how) this components expects the kind of `props` it accepts.
   - **`<Edit>`**
     it's actually used for the `Update` operations and is therefore used at endpoints where you're fetching one (a specific) data object e.g `/users/1` or `/books/12`. In essence, you fetching a particular user or book (and not the entire list).

So with that understanding and explanation, the simple answer is...
**no, you cannot embed a `Datagrid` inside of an `Edit` form**.

It will literally require you to re-write the two components which defeats the essence of using them in the first place (for this scenario).

Answer (score 0):

```
<ArrayField source='bids'>
  <Datagrid>
    <TextField source='id' />
  </Datagrid>
</ArrayField>
```